# Is there a way to 'click' a button in a macOS preference pane without using AppleScript?

Tags: swift, macos

I figured out that I can open a specific preference pane using the following method:
`NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/System/Library/PreferencePanes/%name%.prefPane"))`
where `%name%` is the name of the preference pane.

Now I want to click a button from that preference pane using Swift. All of the solutions I've seen so far use some sort of AppleScript, but I would like to avoid this if possible and just use Swift. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It can be done with the Accessibility API. But your app will need Accessibility permission in System Preferences to do that, so....

Comment: @NickMoore I'm not opposed to giving it a shot. Do you know of a good resource on how to do this? I'm not finding much in my google ventures.

Comment: A good starting point is https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/UIElementInspector/Introduction/Intro.html